# Enviando una consulta POST django intenta acceder a la dirección /POST

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, post

Hice una página web donde actualizo los artículos de Todo. Sin embargo, cuando presiono el botón de guardar, devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Not Found: /todo/POST
[06/Dec/2020 18:39:53] "GET /todo/POST?csrfmiddlewaretoken=IfSoCIJhrDKRYd97eiFKGkOB7BQAcq9XRNi9UZP0pSl55jatHta2i7ffHiGj6Lkt&title=Make+website+right&memo=Inchallah H
TTP/1.1" 404 2985
```

Creo que está buscando una página con el índice POST cuando quiero hacer una solicitud POST para actualizar todo el asunto.

Aquí está la plantilla `viewtodo.html` de la página que muestra y permite actualizar los objeto Todo:

```
{% extends 'todo/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{{ error }}

{{ todo.title }}

<form action="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Este es parte de `view.py` que devuelve mi página web `viewtodo.html` y que debería permitir modificarlos:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from .forms import TodoForm
from .models import Todo

...

def viewtodo(request, todo_pk):
    # grab the todo from the primary key
    todo = get_object_or_404(Todo, pk=todo_pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = TodoForm(instance=todo)
        return render(request, 'todo/viewtodo.html', {'todo': todo, 'form': form})
    else:
        try:
            form = TodoForm(request.POST, instance=todo)
            form.save()
            return redirect('currenttodos')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'todo/viewtodo.html', {'todo': todo, 'form': form,
                                                          'error': 'Bad Info'})
```

Y este es mi archivo de las URL:

```
# Todos
path('', views.home, name="home"),
path('current/', views.currenttodos, name="currenttodos"),
path('todo/<int:todo_pk>', views.viewtodo, name="viewtodo"),
path('create/', views.createtodo, name="createtodo")
...
```

Comment: en `form action="POST"` está mal, con el action indicas a que archivo/ruta deberia redirigirse, tienes que usar el method en ves del action `form method="POST"`

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas el tag  el atributo 'action' indica en que URI se debe procesar la información que vas a mandar con el formulario, el atributo 'method' indica que metodo HTTP debe de usar el navegador para enviar el formulario: POST o GET.

Iria algo asi:

```
{% extends 'todo/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{{ error }}

{{ todo.title }}

<form action="{% url 'createtodo' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Esto de arriba es suponiendo que la url es 'create/' y usando el sistema de tags de django. De otra forma lo puedes escribir manualmente asi: action="todo/" en lugar de action="{% url 'createtodo' %}"

Puedes saber mas sobre la etiqueta form aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/form